# Cloning objects in Java

Tags: java, clone

An abstract taken from Herbert Schildt book on Java

> Cloning is a potentially dangerous action, because it can 
>       cause unintended side effects. For example, if the object 
>       being cloned contains a reference variable called obRef, 
>       then when the clone is made, obRef in the clone will refer
>       to the same object as does obRef in the original. 
>       If the clone makes a change to the contents of the object 
>       referred to by obRef, then it will be changed for the original object, too.

So when the object is being cloned, do the references pointing to that 
original object also gets cloned and as such these points to to the cloned object?

I am confused at this line "...obRef in the clone will refer
    to the same object as does obRef in the original...".

Comment: No, it's the other way around. The fields of the cloned object will contain references to the same objects as the fields of the original object. In other words: the copy will be a shallow one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the difference between references to the original object, and references *within* the original object.

Suppose you have an object `myObj` of type `MyClass` which contains a field of type `ArrayList` named myList.

When you constructed this object, myList was initialized with `new ArrayList()` and is now pointing to an object in the VM's heap.

Now suppose you clone `myObj`

```
MyClass myClone = myObj.clone();
```

The variable `myClone` is pointing to a different object than myObj. They are two distinct objects. However, the `myList` field inside of `myObj` is pointing *to the same object* in the heap as `myList` in `myClone`. This is because when you clone, the references are copied as-is, there is no `new ArrayList()` that assigns a separate object to `myList` in the new object.

No references are ever changed automatically, so any references to your old `myObj` still point to it. The only reference you have to the new object is `myClone` until you assign it to additional variables. But the same is true for `myList`. So the two objects point to the same `ArrayList`. So if one of them adds to it, the other one sees the added values.

Normally, that's not what you need.

Comment: The ArrayList object created wasn't cloned. Only the reference to this list, but not so with the primitive data types.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, I have a class called Another as shown :

```
public class Another {
     int number;
     String message;
     // And so on.
}
```

And another class called CloneMe overriding clone() method ,as shown :

```
public class CloneMe {
   int version;
   Another another;

   public CloneMe(int newVersion, Another obj) {
       this.version = newVersion;
       this.another = obj;
   }
   // and so on

   @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone(); // You can also provide your own implementation here
    }
}
```

Now, when you create an object of class **CloneMe** :

```
  CloneMe actualObject = new CloneMe(10, new Another());
```

Then an instance of class **Another** is created and is assigned to reference *another* in your CloneMe class.

Now, when you call :

```
  CloneMe clonedObject = actualObject.clone();
```

Then only a new instance of **CloneMe** is created with existing state of the *actualObject*. However, no new instance of any other class (for example, Another in our case) is created but the same object reference is assigned to the reference variable in the *clonedObject*. This is called **shallow cloning**.